# Retrieving Data::Dumper elements

Tags: perl, soap, data-dumper

I'm using Data::Dumper to retrieve information from a server with SOAP messaging and need some assistance with assigning the return values for processing.  My code is:

```
my $cm = new SOAP::Lite
encodingStyle => '',
uri => "$axltoolkit",
proxy => "https://$cucmip:$axl_port/axl/";

my $res =$cm->getUser(SOAP::Data->name('userid' => "387653"));

unless ($res->fault) {
    $Data::Dumper::Incident=3;
    my( $reply ) = $res->paramsall();
    my ($devices) = $reply->{user}{associatedDevices}{device};
    print $devices->[0]."\n";
    print $devices->[1]."\n";
    print $devices->[2]."\n";
```

{device} could contain any number of elements so instead of calling out $devices->[0],[1],etc - is it possible to spit out all of the returned devices?  I've tried $_ and @_ but no luck since it just returns the first of the devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Simply apply "Use Rule 1" from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Using-References

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean

```
foreach my $device (@$devices) {
    print "$device\n";
}
```

?

Or more concisely

```
print "$_\n" foreach @$devices;
```

Comment: Or even more concisely `say for @$devices;` :)

Comment: Thanks for the help mob.  For some reason the first suggestion didn't work for me but the second did and it's easier to use anyway.  'preciate it!